# OV7670 and arduino

Tags: image, arduino, atmega

I try to use an ov7670 (http://www.voti.nl/docs/OV7670.pdf) with arduino (atmega328p-pu), to take pictures. I connected differents PIN of ov7670 on my arduino, but i don't know how to make the link between ov7670 and arduino (link of data).

I searched during long weeks and I didn't find tutorials or same projects to understand much better how I can connect arduino and ov7670.

I don't use AL422 with ov7670, it's a problem ?

Sorry, I am a beginner with this component and I would like to learn it :)

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here maybe:
https://github.com/arndtjenssen/ov7670

Then when you have some code come back if you get stuck. Happy coding!